# Regresar una fecha tipo string con formato específico a formato fecha Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

les cuento el problema con el que estoy lidiando.

Estoy usando app junto con una paquetería que se llama ***date-fns***
Lo que pasa es que al mostrar la fecha en mi app, tengo que hacer una conversión, digamos:

```
format(fromUnixTime(gasto.data().fecha), "dd 'de' MMMM 'de' yyyy", {locale: es})
```

Lo importante es que estoy sacando una fecha en formato unix de una base de datos y la devuelve en el formato que le especifico.
Por ejemplo:

```
format(fromUnixTime(1644170400, "dd 'de' MMMM 'de' yyyy", {locale: es})
```

La fecha en formato Unix corresponde al 6 de febrero y en la salida me devuelve: "06 de febrero de 2022".

Todo bien hasta ahí, pero esa salida es del tipo string. Y lo que yo quiero es regresar esta misma salida (que se almacena en un estado o variable que se llama fecha) a un formato de fecha válido para poder guardar esta nueva fecha en mi base de datos, esto porque estoy usando una función de editar para poder guardar la nueva fecha, en caso de que el usuario la quiera cambiar.

En resumen. Digamos que ustedes tienen la variable

```
const fecha = "06 de febrero de 2022"
```

¿Cómo le harían para regresarla a un formato tipo fecha (dígase formato Javascript o Unix)? No he encontrado la manera de hacerlo.

Comment: Que usas como backend para guardar la información??

Answer (score 0):

Puedes implementar una pequeña función para parsear la fecha. Te adjunto un ejemplo. Ten en cuenta que este ejemplo no valida la fecha, simplemente la intenta parsear del string que le pasas como parámetro.

```js
function parseLongDate(longStringFormat) {
  const months = ["enero", "febrero", "marzo", "abril", "mayo", "junio", "julio", "agosto", "septiembre", "octubre", "noviembre", "diciembre"]
  const regex = /\s+del?\s+/gi;
  const date = longStringFormat.trim().split(regex);
  const day = Number.parseInt(date[0]);
  const month = months.indexOf(date[1].toLowerCase());
  const year = Number.parseInt(date[2]);

  return new Date(year, month, day);
}

let result = parseLongDate("06 de febrero de 2022")
console.log(result);   // String parseada a Date

// Para convertirla de nuevo a la string original puedes usar
let options = {year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };
    
console.log(result.toLocaleDateString('es-ES', options));
```

Pero si tienes la opción de que te de la fecha en un formato específico, pues has que tu servidor te la devuelva con formato `YYYY-MM-DD` y así puedes parsearla directamente sin necesidad de implementar nada:

```js
const fecha = "2021-02-06";  // string con la fecha en formato YYYY-MM-DD
const parts = fecha.split("-");
const fechaObjeto = new Date(parts[0], parts[1]-1, parts[2]); // los meses para JS comienzan en 0


// Para imprimirlo o obtenerlo en el formato que especificas
let options = {year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };
console.log(fechaObjeto.toLocaleDateString('es-ES', options));
```

Otra opción puede ser usar una libreríá externa como `momentjs`.